# Delete a row from a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table of rows and a button to delete it in each row.
I can remove a row bot the problem is that I need to update the value deleteRow(nb_of_rows) in every time I remove a row

[image]

This is the table code in HTML

```
<input type="button" id="insert_row" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row()" >
<br><br>

<table id="mytable" width="100%" border="2"  >
    <tr>
        <th>Sr.</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Delete</th>   
    </tr>

</table>
```

and this is JavaScript code

```
var srn = 0;
function insert_row(){

    var table = document.getElementById("mytable")

    var nb_of_rows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length;

    var row = table.insertRow(nb_of_rows);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);

    cell1.innerHTML = changeSR(); 

    var delete_btn = document.createElement("input");
    delete_btn.type = "button";
    delete_btn.className = "btn";
    delete_btn.value = "Delete";


    cell6.appendChild(delete_btn);


    delete_btn.onclick = function deleteRow(){

        return document.getElementById("mytable").deleteRow(nb_of_rows);
    }


}

function changeSR(){

    return srn = srn + 1 ;

}
```

and this is an online share of my code
[enter link description here](http://tpcg.io/uk4QsQ)

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. Maybe I didn't describe the question very well because of my bad English. Thank you again for thehelp. I just learnt JS in the last two days so I make many simple mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because the index in `nb_of_rows` is in danger of being out of date by the time the button is clicked (especially if other rows and have been added and deleted in the meantime). Therefore it will either delete the wrong row, or crash because the index doesn't exist in the table any more.

The solution is fairly simple: make the button get the parent row it belongs to, and then get that row's current index at the point of deletion, rather than relying on the index it had when it was added.

Usefully the [row element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) has an index property telling you its current index in the table body, which makes this solution possible.

Here's the event code you need:

```
delete_btn.onclick = function deleteRow() {
    var row = this.parentElement.parentElement; //get the parent of the parent (i.e. the first parent is the table cell, and the parent of that is the row)
    document.getElementById("mytable").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
}
```

(BTW it makes no sense really to have a `return` statement in an event handler, since the control returns to somewhere in the JS event-handling engine, not to your code, so I removed that at the same time.)

Demo:

```js
var srn = 0;

function insert_row() {

  var table = document.getElementById("mytable")

  var nb_of_rows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length;

  var row = table.insertRow(nb_of_rows);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);

  cell1.innerHTML = changeSR();

  var delete_btn = document.createElement("input");
  delete_btn.type = "button";
  delete_btn.className = "btn";
  delete_btn.value = "Delete";

  cell6.appendChild(delete_btn);

  delete_btn.onclick = function deleteRow() {
    var row = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    document.getElementById("mytable").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
  }
}

function changeSR() {

  return srn = srn + 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="insert_row" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row()">
<br><br>

<table id="mytable" width="100%" border="2">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```